# Reference inherited class functions

Tags: python, multithreading, inheritance, berkeley-db

I am inheriting from both threading.Thread and bdb.Bdb.  Thread requires a run function for the start function to call, and I need to user the Bdb.run function.  How do I reference Bdb's run function since I can't do it with self.run?  I tried super, but I'm apparently not using that right, I get TypeError: must be type, not classobj.

```
import sys
import os
import multiprocessing
import threading
import bdb

from bdb import Bdb
from threading import Thread

from el_tree_o import ElTreeO, _RUNNING, _PAUSED, _WAITING
from pysignal import Signal

class CommandExec(Thread, Bdb):
    '''
    Command Exec is an implementation of the Bdb python class with is a base
    debugger.  This will give the user the ability to pause scripts when needed
    and see script progress through line numbers.  Useful for command and
    control scripts.
    '''

    def __init__(self, mainFile, skip=None):
        Bdb.__init__(self,skip=skip)
        Thread.__init__(self)

        # need to define botframe to protect against an error
        # generated in bdb.py when set_quit is called before
        # self.botframe is defined
        self.botframe = None

        # self.even is used to pause execution
        self.event = threading.Event()

        # used so I know when to start debugging
        self.mainFile = mainFile
        self.start_debug = 0

        # used to run a file
        self.statement = ""

    def run(self):
        self.event.clear()
        self.set_step()
        super(bdb.Bdb,self).run(self.statement)
```

Comment: Are you quite sure that your `CommandExec` is a thread *and* a database?  Could it perhaps be that it *has* a database?

Comment: To use super, you would change that line to `super(CommandExec, self).run(self.statement)`.  In python 3: `super().run(self.statement)`.  You're getting the super class of CommandExec, not the super class of Bdb. :)

Answer (score 4):

Just as you invoked Bdb's `__init__` method on line 22, you can invoke its run method:

```
Bdb.run(self, self.statement)
```

`super` is only useful when you don't know which parent class you need to invoke next, and you want to let Python's inheritance machinery figure it out for you.  Here, you know precisely which function you want to call, `Bdb.run`, so just call it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I tried that and got:TypeError: unbound method run() must be called with Bdb instance as first argument (got str instance instead) ... any ideas

Comment: @user1313404: Notice the arguments I used:  Bdb.run(self, self.statement)

Comment: Bdb is that Base Debugger, not the berkeley database ... still the question is valid.  I missed the self as the argument .. so my bad, I added self as the first argument and it worked fine ... thank you for your help.